# Hyundai Santa Fe 2012 - low beam of the headlights stopped working

Tags: troubleshooting, hyundai, headlight, santa-fe, bulbs

it came to my attention last night that BOTH of the **low beam** headlights of my Hyundai Santa Fe 2012 stopped working, the high beams worked fine - as shown in the picture below.

After reading posts online, it could be a burned out bulb issue, or relay issue or fuse issue. I might want to check out the bulbs first (even though it'd surprise me  BOTH bulbs were burned but the same time, but as someone pointed out it's not unheard of). My questions are more like:

- How do a low beam bulb looks like, and where can I find one? All
  pictures I can find is a small-sized highbeam, the low beam, from
  what I see, however, looks like a regular curve-sharped one.
- Any good instructions of replacing a lowbeam bulb for the model of my car?
- If it turns out not a bulb issue, how can I further troubleshooting
  the issue? can I find instructions to change relays/fuses?

[image]

Comment: If the low beam is also the daytime running lights then it would not surprise me that they both went out together.  Solar Mike and PeteCon give good answers for the next first steps in figuring out the problem. I would just like to add that If all that fails to fix your problems then you may want to start testing your light switch and controlling module for failure next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to a car spares store. They'll spec the correct bulbs for your vehicle, and they'll also install them for you if it's a quiet day (and they'll know not to touch the bulbs, which would otherwise cause them to blow in short order). If the problem is a fuse or anything else simple, they'll be able to quickly tell you. And they don't charge for this service..

Comment: thank you, I went to Autozone and the nice sale girl helped replace the bulbs, but one of them was due to the poor wire contact.

Answer (score 1):

Well, check the fuse box and test the fuses - fuses can fracture so that current won't flow but they still "look" good...

Also check the bulbs from both headlights, a multimeter is good for this but putting them across a battery with a wire to finish the circuit also works (be careful not to cause a spark as that can ignite any gas...)...

Comment: thank you, it turned out one bulb burned out, the other was due to poor wire contact